# Rectify a rectangle to get area

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I need to get the area of a known object inside a scene to get the distance from that. The problem is rectifying it so that the area is independent from the angle. 
I'm using opencv (on Android) with some java code that is equivalent to this:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

In other words: how do i get the area of the object observed perpendicularly from that distance given the H matrix.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call cvCalibrateCamera, but am not sure if it works with one image only. The [algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf) it is based upon can cope with the one image case, see section 3.1. where it says "if n=1...". So in a pinch you can re-implement it.